# Defining react component interface using typeof operator and passing props to it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

I'm having problem defining interface for functional React component and passing props to it.
Error is reproduced [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQGjgVQGc0AhCAVwDsATAZRmlznsYEExg4BfOAMyggg4AIgBe5QjAw1hAbgBQoSLERxCACwwAbLRADu3PgKEBycZOnUA9Bu269JhfPlWrAGWCS1DdHEtxgGBNCNTQtNGQfQnk0AA9leGBKbCheDGQ0OABJD0l6LEyEeTg4KQBzQgAuVQBrNABPaskoJLLZOAA3bXI0JpgWyjLuAG0AXQUS4Go%20gbb5Lhj46ETktFT0zJzPGBZfOOwaEK28qWxEYtCYABUMCuqACnKq7Nyd07RhkyeTUYBKOAAvAA%20ToQKYKBZxBIoCCULwSNCvXaZAEodAFAA8xzejCB91%2093uxBg-2BcHuRRKT2qYxwFym1WEwjpJWJNzu5KepJBxMJ3PJSGpcGGADoxU9Rtxfr86VxpU4ocsYXD4FptrQwhEfIDyRZsNVscj%20RSLkK9WgRU8WZd2c9zSK2bdCLLfk5XABRNxoEBoZLeRh%20GgBIIhYjhSLQaKKlRJFJpDLZd3hH3JfJnSmlJ3VJB1RreWbtLpaHozVojcYXSgYH2lwYQxbQ2NreObJPe304vaxA7UI5tlNvArnVloa5ZznjrL9jtpj5fJ0-fkdMHUevR%20DIWHw4jT1M%20FFozDYLG7ztoPEEomj40ZoW0yvV3oiZkXR0cx5O-m8-GAkEUzMcqK4pOpKcoyvM8rOOuypeJqA4auG2qokS7wGqeRq-gKprjvaVqvqOtp9AUDoEU6LoKksMarOsCZZOyAAK0hhMO-roNUMD1GAaAQLwcAIki%205wAAPqUnHcbxCLofuEyhIh0DsWJPFwGqeSahGUDCaJXFKXBM5qT47TzM4rgcVxcAAOKjsiVxiRiVwgqiVxwPsvq9gQxBkFQdD7hiyLsMAGJJLwaxwAAGkCIIAPxhXA1SUGgHRrBR0K8FQkTALCcAMUxWj3GAAhgM8dG3Ix8VaP8GYlK4fGUOgWgFNQzlQAIUDOgE4DLNIG6aIMmSeKUmjwDA6iZMgdjBmGvGUBAymwmUIVrC10QlCUm4qqoVo2k6hiovlECFQ6%2055QVhAkXJUB4LYOj6K6RlAA).

It interface defined as

```
//Two zustand stores and their selectors
import { selector as listSelector, useListStore } from '../stores/list-form-store';
import { selector as elementSelector,useElementStore } from '../stores/element-form-store';
import { shallow } from 'zustand/shallow';

export interface ITagPanel {
  store: typeof useListStore | typeof useElementStore;
  selector: typeof listSelector | typeof elementSelector; 
}

export function TagPanel(props: ITagPanel) {
  const {tags, setTags} = props.store(props.selector, shallow);
```

`TagPanel` need to accept several several different zustand stores and their selectors, so that `TagPanel` can be reused. `props.store(props.selector, shallow);` generates the error:

```
Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.
```

Two stores above are defined as:

```
export const useElementStore = create<IElementStore>()((set) => ({...
export const useListStore = create<IListStore>()((set) => ({
```

If I'm `useListStore` directly, doesn't generate the same error:

```
const {tags, setTags} = useListStore(listSelector, shallow);
```

Comment: Can you please repro the error in a playground? It'd like to help but it is unclear from the  question what type is `create` too. you should be able to inline the types that you have now with `declare function ...` so you do not have to copy the actual implementation.

Comment: This is because the stores have conflicting overloads which result in `never`, leaving only the overload with 0 arguments. You could try to use [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ1DaN) but it's dirty and I don't know if it works with your other code, which is why you should include all relevant code.

Comment: @AntonKastritskiy I will post link to playground.

Comment: @AntonKastritskiy 
I have update the question and added bug to the playground that perfectly reproduces this bug.

Comment: @vr.  
question is updated with link that reproduces the bug.

Comment: Maybe you should really be using generics? https://tsplay.dev/N759PW This isn't the cleanest yet but it works. You could try refactoring the common properties `tags` and `setTags` under one common interface.

Comment: @vr.
plz, post this as an as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using generic parameters instead of using a union:

```
export interface ITagPanel<
  StoreType extends TagsStoreType,
  U extends TagsStoreType
> {
  store: UseBoundStore<StoreApi<StoreType>>;
  selector: (state: StoreType) => U;
}

export function TagPanel<T extends TagsStoreType, U extends TagsStoreType>(
  props: ITagPanel<T, U>
) {
  const { tags, setTags } = props.store(props.selector, shallow);
}
```

where the generic parameters are constrained by this type:

```
type TagsStoreType = {
  tags: { key: string; value: string }[];
  setTags: (tags: { key: string; value: string }[]) => void;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQGjgVQGc0AhCAVwDsATAZRmlznsYEExg4BfOAMyggg4AIgBe5QjAw1hAbgBQoSLERxCACwwAbLRADu3PgKFiJUmgHoN23Xrnz5FiwBlgktQ3Rxp1OMBgA5IRqaFpoyJ6E8mgAHsrwwJTYULwYyGhwAJKukvRYGQjycHBSAOaEAFyqANZoAJ5VklCJpbJwAG7a5GiNMM2UpdwA2gC6CsXA1L39rfJc0XHQCUloKWkZ2W4wLF6x2DTBm7lS2IhFITAAKhjlVQAUZZVZOdsnaEPCj8IjAJRwALwAPg6EEmCnmsXiKAglHcEjQLx2GX+KHQ+QAPEdXoxAXcfnc7sQYH8gXA7oVio8qqMcOdJlVhMJacUiddbmTHiTgUSCVyyUgqXAhgA6UWPEbcH4-WlcKUKBZQ5Aw9xaLa0ULhTwAsmSfJVLFIvnk86C3XYYWPZkXNlPM1oYWsm6EGU-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-KdPKmC8xyDiq8oWtxc4wAEMAnkyCyrK0dFLjwfBAXkP4Mxw+ABXohTykMFE+ogAaHQPO41o2jKIygPBrB0fQMPmIA)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure of how you want to use this and if I understand it correctly, but using generic types as mention and abstract type for common properties might be a solution ? [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQGjgVQGc0AhCAVwDsATAZRmlznsYEExg4BfOAMyggg4AIgBe5QjAw1hAbgBQoSLERxCACwwAbLRADu3PgKEBycZOnUA9Bu269JhfPlWrcAOJpKaKMGRwAFQBPMDR5NAAPZXhgSmwoXgxkNDgASVYAI0koJJh6LBSEeTg4KQBzQgAuVQBrNCDq7Niy2TgAN21yNEaYX0oy7gBtAF0FEuIYAIwK6oAKcqq0zOzc-OxBkwWTYYBKOABeAD52iGBqBS5nSOjSkJTPb19kWjQtNGQGKAAeALhI7BohCWWV6qyk2GO%20zgsws2GqAT2R2hRRKC3hGy2wxwxTUaEm00WAUGwgmUwqwix8i4Oyc12gMTiPkSyTSZIACtJXj8-hEAdQgekQTkPms0McUWpPt0CMQyFQ6FKvix0OxgD9DocccQ3h9oNUHj4-C8dZ91RdnK5AtMOd4tOEovS%20FQPsAIJQrWUbVzfv8vPzgSsReCxbMwAIwItUuzOVp1XsJSVkG7JKoFnhSQTDFCwxAIwA6SSMUPhwgF17vT7pzQ6fQ0nEldAwchQd1fQ55jtfKyHc0WtwAETQvFiKSCFCgKAkDCEMDuQN40DSABlgJJRfabrF4syUqkV2vgzy%20QLlqCgwVEDizj0%20i0qRvHUnKCmJGh93kpQcUOgCl896uPwKQ5ZhhPFEWOWYJTROARmxEprxEYQ4NxfEZmhBZwJQkDMMg0oCWqQYOzzBZhm4HYdmxak6zpFQnxTLQAONCs9QNJ4mN1b5-wPICvxhYNqi4wDsBwqD8MlApiIJZCMzQ2E0DLVDCGQhC5LzM5KLrPs4EHYdvDgMdm0nQsZznPhF1SABRN4QC8ISwhohltySXcrLQGy4lFI8-RPIUwQvCVKAwGyb2ac0HJQZN4FfVz3I-Rgv1QTBsD-GLbNFYDQJgEScWg2CcUC4LEOkvEyUWeYCUwiZsIOCCkFyoiSLIiiqXIhRwro%20BUo88sOMqVijR601LOstLg0haE5IErq7Oy1ExNUtMtRK%20bgwU0rkIK6VVM2jSnC0iyIjcsA3jgCBeDgV84GqeQOrgEAgnfL0tEqKNrRjP933Sr8JULdBqlfT6pWKk09TgBi10G6BKKcH43ttRAiPux6Yy4bsgA)